# Mongoose - operate with documents from an existing DB without knowing the exact schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to connect to a mongo database with mongoose to preform a query. I have done similar before but in that case I defined the schema and the model so I made operations with the exported then required model in the application.

For this task I was provided with the mongoose connection's uri and the collections's name only and I have to make a node app and query the collection.

What is the way to query the collection with mongoose in this case?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be good to go with below code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("uri");

var abcSchema = new Schema({
    strict: false
}, {
    collection: 'collectionName'
});
var abc = mongoose.model('collectionName', abcSchema);
abc.operations...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

So I have to define a schema without keys and I have to provide the existing collection's name, that's all? When I define a schema like this it will not overwrite the already defined schema for the collection?

Comment: No this will not hurt the existing schema in any way. The only issue with this is you can add any key to the collection if not explicitly checked.

Comment: Yes, it is working well, thanks very much for your help!